# How do I restore the default Windows 10 bootloader?

Tags: grub, windows-10, bootloader

I would like to remove by Ubuntu partition by formatting its drive in the Windows Disk Manager. However, how can I restore the Windows 10 bootloader after this action? I no longer wish to use GRUB.

Comment: Do the answers on this question help you? http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: Brilliant! Looks like `bootrec /fixmbr` is what I'm looking for and my Windows install disk. Thank you, sigalor!